# Remove array inside the array if [conditions] index has no null

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is array output

```
Array
(
    [conditions] => Array
        (
            [Service.organization_size_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [limit] => 10
    [joins] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => inner
                    [conditions] => Array
                        (
                            [ServicesToOrganizationTypes.organization_type_id] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => 1
                                )

                            [0] => ServicesToOrganizationTypes.service_id = Service.id
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => LEFT
                    [conditions] => Array
                        (
                            [ServicesToLifeCycles.life_cycle_id] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => 1
                                )

                            [0] => ServicesToLifeCycles.service_id = Service.id
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [type] => inner
                    [conditions] => Array
                        (
                            [servicestoindustries.industry_id] => 
                            [0] => servicestoindustries.service_id = Service.id
                        )

                )
        )

    [group] => Service.id
)
```

I want to remove a array part if  [conditions] has no value for exmple below

```
[3] => Array
                   (
                       [type] => inner
                       [conditions] => Array
                           (
                               [servicestoindustries.industry_id] => // here has no value 
                               [0] => servicestoindustries.service_id = Service.id
                           )

                   )
```

So i want to remove it from array

```
[3] => Array
                   (
                       [type] => inner
                       [conditions] => Array
                           (
                               [servicestoindustries.industry_id] =>                      // here has no value 
                               [0] => servicestoindustries.service_id = Service.id
                           )

                   )
```

Comment: What you want to remove from ? `array` or `array element` ?

Comment: i want to remove it [3] => Array
                   (
                       [type] => inner
                       [conditions] => Array
                           (
                               [servicestoindustries.industry_id] =>                      // here has no value 
                               [0] => servicestoindustries.service_id = Service.id
                           )

                   )

Comment: if has [conditions] => Array ( [servicestoindustries.industry_id] => // here has no value

Comment: ok. That `[3] => ....` always comes in the same index of `3`. Because we need to define static.

Comment: no no it can be anything like  [3] => Array
                (
                    [type] => inner
                    [conditions] => Array
                        (
                            [servicestoindustries.industry_id] =>  0r  [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => LEFT
                    [conditions] => Array
                        (
                            [ServicesToLifeCycles.life_cycle_id]

Comment: You mean it may occurs in all the inner arrays. like `[0] => .. organization_type_id` , `[1] => .. life_cycle_id`, `[3] => ... industry_id` right?

Comment: [0] => .. organization_type_id , [1] => .. life_cycle_id, [3] => ... industry_id if has no value then remove all array element

Comment: fine. Let me work out.

Comment: Is there any reason to jump index key of `2` `0,1, ,3`

Comment: @Ranjith please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162162/remove-array-element-if-condition-index-has-no-value-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one (untested)

```
<?php
/**
 * A redundant function to clean array
 */
function clean_array(&$array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            clean_array($value); // If array, call the function itself
        } else if(empty($value)) {
            // Two choices
            unset($array[$key]); // Delete the array part
            unset($array) // Delete the whole array
        }
    }
}
```